# WindowsAzure.AD.Graph.2013_04_05 - How long is this valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an MVC App which uses Azure AD, it works very well using the WindowsAzure.AD.Graph.2013_04_05 helper project that Microsoft made available.  This project is now outdated, but looking at the new Nuget Package, the two require code changes.

I have two questions, How long can I use the old one before I find myself locked out of my own app.  Second, has anyone migrated between them?

What I have is very simple, its just an Auth Filter which checks if a user is in one or more groups.

Comment: It depends on the underlying REST version that the project is using. In general a REST version must be accepted for more than 1 year after the Microsoft team announces future deprecation of it - so you should have some time. I will ask around as I know this is all documented somewhere. Note that .NET version does not map always to REST version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have at least a year from the announcement of a REST version being deprecated; a REST version is not the same as a NuGet package version, so you'll need to understand the underlying version in use.

Please refer to this Microsoft support policy on Azure-related REST APIs and libraries: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/azure-cloud-lifecycle-faq